# Retrieve all Entities that contains specific letters using criteria expression?

Tags: hibernate

HEllo I have this scenario to search for specific user and the result that should appear is all users that contains the letters in the search text field ex. if I searched for a then results is all users that contain the letter a

I used this method to do so:

```
public List<User> search(String searchName) {
        session=sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        List<User> users=session.createCriteria(User.class).
                        add(Restrictions.like("username", searchName)).list();
        return users;
    }
```

but the result is undefined unless I put the "exact" match for user name example
if I searched for a the result is No User Exists but if I searched for raouf then raouf is retrieved

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `like` clause of HQL/criteria has the same semantics as the `like` clause of SQL. You need to use % to mean "0, one or several characters".

So `Restrictions.like("userName", "%" + searchName + "%")` will return all the users whose userName contains the entered search name (it's case-sensitive, though).

You may also use Restrictions.like("username", searchName, MatchMode.ANYWHERE) which will do that for you.